# Operands of logical operator '.or.' at (!) are Logical(4)/CHARACTER(1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have the following code:

```
print*,"type s for a square and type t for a triangle"
read*,fig
if(fig =='t' .or. 'T') then
print*,"Enter the sides of the triangle"
read*,a,b,c
area=tri(a,b,c)
print*,"The area of the triangle is",area
else if (fig=='s' .or.'S') then 
print*,"Enter the side of the square"
read*,s
area=sq(s)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
intro_fun.f:9:24:

  if(fig == 't' .or. 'T') then
                        1
Error: Operands of logical operator '.or.' at (1) are LOGICAL(4)/CHARACTER(1)
intro_fun.f:14:27:

  else if(fig=='s' .or. 'S') then
                           1
Error: Operands of logical operator '.or.' at (1) are LOGICAL(4)/CHARACTER(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using the statement:

`if(fig == 't' .or. 'T')`

this should be:

`if(fig == 't' .or. fig == 'T')`

Answer (score 1):

Fortran has so many ways of doing this. My first test uses the features of intrinsic comparison to broadcast the comparison against a whole array of values then the `ANY` transformational intrinsic to reduce the array result to the information we are trying to extract. This is a great method for comparing against many values at once and is in my opinion more readable when there are more than two values to compare against.

The second test uses the `SCAN` intrinsic which is how Fortran can find out if there were any characters in the input string that matched any characters in a given string.

The third test uses `VERIFY` which is kind of like `SCAN` but with negative logic.

The fourth test uses `C interoperability` to access the function `toupper` from the `C` library so as to perform a case-insensitive comparison. Have to be careful, though, because that function uses integer inputs and outputs so we have to convert via `IACHAR` and `ACHAR`.

```
program verify_test
   implicit none
   character fig
   integer i
! verify.txt must exist in the current directory
! and have one character on each of the first two lines.
   open(10,file='verify.txt',status='old')
   do i = 1, 2
      read(10,'(a)') fig
      write(*,'(*(g0))') "ANY(fig == ['t','T']) = ",ANY(fig == ['t','T'])
      write(*,'(*(g0))') "SCAN(fig,'tT') /= 0 = ",SCAN(fig,'tT') /= 0
      write(*,'(*(g0))') "VERIFY(fig,'tT') == 0 = ",VERIFY(fig,'tT') == 0
BLOCK
   interface
      function toupper(c) bind(C,name='toupper')
         use ISO_C_BINDING
         implicit none
         integer(C_INT) toupper
         integer(C_INT), value :: c
      end function toupper
   end interface
   write(*,'(*(g0))') "achar(toupper(iachar(fig))) == 'T' = ",achar(toupper(iachar(fig))) == 'T'
END BLOCK
   end do
end program verify_test
```